# Degree calculator using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I was making a program in `tkinter` that you enter your degree and it will multiply it by 5 and it will change the label to your degree is:degree  but the label doesn't change.

My code.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

root = Tk()

def getVal():
    val=ent1.get()
    degree = (int(val) * 5)
    print (degree)

ent1 = Entry(root)
ent1.pack()

butt1 = Button(root, text="Click Me", command=getVal)
butt1.pack()

w = Label(root, text="Your Degree Is:" %degree)
w.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The label doesn't change because you don't have any code that even attempts to change it; all you do is `print` something.

Comment: `degree` is not defined in the scope where you are using it. Also, is there any reason for using tkinter? If you want GUI, there are better free options.

Comment: Also, `"your Degree Is: " %degree` is just going to raise a `TypeError`. If you want to use `%`-formatting for strings, you have to have a `%s` in the format string.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Use formatting tools to make your post more readable. It will get more attention if readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have at least three problems in your code:

1. Your `Label` constructor is trying to use `degree`, but it doesn't exist at the top level, only as a local variable within `getVal`.
2. Your `Label` constructor is trying to `%`-format a string that doesn't have any `%` specifiers in it.
3. Your `getVal` function doesn't even attempt to change the label's text, it just `print`s out a value.

What you want is probably something like:

```
def getVal():
    val=ent1.get()
    degree = (int(val) * 5)
    w.config(text="Your Degree Is: %s" % (degree,))
# ...
w = Label(root, text="Your Degree Is:")
# ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm new to tkinter and python :)